# Find function on mongoose issue

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to return a set of documents stored in a database via mongoose. What I want to do is filter the results and get the set of results that match the passed userid.

This is my user.js

```
module.exports.findMatchID = function(userid,callback)
{
const q3 = {userid: userid};
User.model2.find(q3,callback);

}
```

and this is my approutes.js

```
route.post('/manageproject',function(req,res)
{
const userid = req.body.userid._id;

User.findMatchID(userid,function(err,user) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) {
       return res.json({state: false, msg: "Not found"});
    }
    else{
        res.json({
            state:true,
            user:{
                id:user._id,
                proTitle:user.proTitle,
                proDescription:user.proDescription,
                memberList:user.memberList,
                edc:user.edc
                 }
               });
       }
   });
});
```

I just keep getting a {} as the result object with nothing in it. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this? The findOne function works well as expected but I only get one document back.

Comment: The `user` in your callback is an array, but you're treating it like a single doc.

Comment: Do I have to define another function to loop it through the results?

Comment: You'd need to iterate over the array or directly index into it, depending on what you're trying to do. But why aren't you just using `findOne` here? Aren't you expecting a single user in the result?

Comment: No, whats happening here is the db has a collection of books recorded along with the user id. I match the id of the person currently logged in and I want to retrieve all the documents(books) which has that user id recorded.